# Segmentation fault issue while reversing linked list in c

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *insert(struct node *link, int data) {
    if (link == NULL) {
        link = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        link->data = data;
        link->next = NULL;
    } else {
        struct node *newlink = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        newlink->data = data;
        newlink->next = link;
        link = newlink;
    }
    return link;
}

void reverse(struct node *link) {
    int i, j = 0;
    int arr1[100], arr2[100];
    struct node *current;
    int count = 0;

    current = link;

    while (current != NULL) {
        arr1[i] = current->data;
        i = i + 1;
        count = count + 1;
        current = current->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    for (i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        arr2[j] = arr1[i];
        j = j + 1;
    }

    printf("The elements in the linked list are: ");

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr1[i]);
    }

    printf("The elements in the reversed linked list are: ");

    for (j = 0; j < count; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr2[j]);
    }
}

void print(struct node *link) {
    struct node *temp = link;

    printf("The elements in the linked list are: ");

    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void main() {
    int value;

    printf("Enter the value:\n");
    scanf("%d", &value);
    struct node *link = NULL;

    link = insert(link, value);
    char ans[3] = "yes";

    while (ans[0] == 'y') {
        printf("Do you want to add another node? Type Yes/No\n");
        scanf("%s", ans);

        if (ans[0] == 'y') {
            printf("Enter the value:\n");
            scanf("%d", &value);
            link = insert(link, value);
        } else {
            reverse(link);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code I wrote to reverse a single linked list in C. I seem to try different combinations of the program but while doing it by array method, I am unable to get rid of the segmentation fault, and hence it doesn't give output.

Comment: can you please share the stack trace of the core dump

Comment: Sorry @TanmayPatil : The compiler I have been doing is a 3rd party one for evaluation purpose:  doesnt show any stack trace , so currently I wont be able to

Comment: `arr1[i]=current->data;` uses the *unitialised variable* `i`. The subsequent `i=0;` is too late, even useless since the immediately following loop is `for(i=count-1; ...)`

Comment: yes . i  could be beyond 99 and can cause core dump

Comment: @tron042 it might not produce a stack trace but modern compilers are quite good at giving warnings.

Comment: @WeatherVane : after putting it as "int i=0;int j=0" and evaluating , I get an infinite loop of just the first element inserted. Lets say the first element inserted is 9 , so infinite loop of 9

Comment: If you are evaluating a compiler, start with code that you know works. If you have faulty code, then use a compiler that does what you need. Simple. But complicated if you mix two aims in the same exercise.

Comment: `for (j = 0; j < count; i++)`: When you're using `j`, it's probably a mistake to increment `i`.

Comment: Get a modern free compiler and a debugger.

Comment: @tron042: What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems in your code:

- `i` is uninitialized when used in the `while` loop in function `reverse`, causing undefined behavior which could explain the `segmentation fault`.
- `j` is not modified in the loop at the end of the `reverse` function, causing an infinite loop:

  ```
  for (j = 0; j < count; i++) {
      printf("%d ", arr2[j]);
  }
  ```
- you are not reversing the list, you just print the list contents in reverse order, and assume its length is at most `100`.  This is probably not what you are expected to do.
- in function `main`, the array `ans` should be made larger to accommodate at least the word `yes`, and you should prevent `scanf()` from storing more characters into it than would fit. Also reorganize the code to avoid duplication:

  ```
  int main(void) {
      struct node *link = NULL;

      for (;;) {
          char ans[80];
          int value;

          printf("Enter the value:\n");
          if (scanf("%d", &value) != 1)
              break;
          link = insert(link, value);
          printf("Do you want to add another node? Type Yes/No\n");
          if (scanf("%79s", ans) != 1 || ans[0] != 'y') {
              break;
          }
      }
      reverse(link);
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Most of the above problems would have been spotted immediately by increasing the compiler warning level (for example `gcc -Wall -Werror` or `clang -Weverything -Werror`).

Here is a simpler version that reads numbers and allocates the list in the same order as you do, inserting each new element before the previous one, then reverses the list and finally prints it. As expected, the list is printed in the order of entry.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *insert(struct node *head, int data) {
    struct node *newlink = malloc(sizeof(*newlink));
    newlink->data = data;
    newlink->next = head;
    return newlink;
}

struct node *reverse(struct node *link) {
    struct node *prev = NULL;
    while (link) {
        struct node *temp = link->next;
        link->next = prev;
        prev = link;
        link = temp;
    }
    return prev;
}

void print(struct node *link) {
    printf("The elements in the linked list are: ");

    for (struct node *n = link; n; n = n->next) {
        printf("%d ", n->data);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    struct node *link = NULL;
    int value;

    printf("Enter the values, end the list with 0:\n");
    while (scanf("%d", &value) == 1 && value != 0) {
        link = insert(link, value);
    }
    link = reverse(link);
    print(link);
    return 0;
}
```